# CMake custom builds issues

Tags: build, cmake, emscripten

I am trying to use CMake to build a custom project, which involves using emscripten to provide javascript binding for my C++ library.

This is what I want my CMakeLists.txt file to achieve

1. Specify source locations for my files **(DONE)**
2. Set up relevant COMPILERS to use as well as compiler flags etc **(DONE)**
3. Use custom build to generate new cpp files (detailed steps below)

   - use a custom tool (python script) to generate `interface/glue.cpp`
   - Create a new EMPTY file `interface/glue_wrapper.cpp`
   - For each header file `f` in `${my_header_files}` append `#include "f"` to the file `interface/glue_wrapper.cpp`
   - The final entry in `interface/glue_wrapper.cpp` should be `#include "glue.cpp"`
4. Use custom build to generate my javascript file by using the following logic:

   - create a variable ${ALL_SOURCES} containing all the sources listed above in step 1 and `interface/glue_wrapper.cpp` in step 3 above
   - compile using the COMMAND that evaluates to: `${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${ALL_SOURCES} interface/glue_wrapper.cpp --post-js glue.js -o output.js`

I have spent the last 7 hours on step 3 and 4 - with no success.

This is what I have so far (relating to steps 3 and 4 above)

```
# Build Interface
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
                OUTPUT interface/glue.cpp
                COMMAND cd interface
                COMMAND python ${PLATFORM_PREFIX}/tools/webidl_binder.py ${myclasses_INTERFACE} glue
                # Need to loop through list and generate include statements ...
                #COMMAND echo "#include <glue.cpp>" > glue_wrapper.cpp
                 )

# Build JS library
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
                OUTPUT ${PROJECT_JS_DIR}/${PROJECT}.js
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} # Nothing seems to work anyway .... giving up finally :(
                )
```

I am using cmake 3.2.1, and building on Ubuntu 14.0.4. I am trying to create Unix MakeFiles.

My question is this:

**How do I modify the code snippet above, in order to implement the required functionality specified in steps 3 and 4?**

Comment: which part of 3. does work?

Comment: @m.s.: Alas, I have had no success at all with parts 3 and 4. After 7 hours of struggling, I have given up. I can build if I follow the steps outlined manually, but I am trying to use CMake instead of an entirely manual process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the contents of `glue_wrapper.cpp` don't depend on build-time values at all, they're based purely on information available at CMake time (the contents of the `my_header_files` variable). Therefore, you can create the file at CMake time with a simple `file()` command:

```
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/interface/glue_wrapper.cpp)  # erase file if it exists
foreach(header IN LISTS my_header_files ITEMS glue.cpp)
  file(APPEND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/interface/glue_wrapper.cpp "#include \"${header}\"\n")
endforeach()
```

The custom command for creating the .js library should work normally:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${PROJECT_JS_DIR}/${PROJECT}.js
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${ALL_SOURCES} interface/glue_wrapper.cpp --post-js glue.js -o output.js
  DEPENDS ${ALL_SOURCES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/interface/glue_wrapper.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/interface/glue.cpp
  COMMENT "Building ${PROJECT}.js"
  VERBATIM
)
```

As with any CMake custom command, **it will only be included in the build if something depends on its output** (I suspect that is why your approach was failing). So you should add a custom target to drive the command:

```
add_custom_target(
  JsLibrary ALL
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_JS_DIR}/${PROJECT}.js
  COMMENT "Building JsLibrary"
)
```

That should be all that's necessary.

As a side note, notice that `add_custom_command` has a `WORKING_DIRECTORY` argument, which you should use instead of `COMMAND cd`.

---

The CMake relationship between custom commands and custom targets can take some time to fully grok, so I will try to explain what's going on in the code above.

**Custom command**

The command `add_custom_command(OUTPUT x ...)` creates a build rule which produces an output. Basically, this tells CMake:

> If somebody ever needs the file `x`, here is how you create it.

The command does not add anything to the generated buildsystem *by itself.* It only provides information to CMake on how a file would be created.

The individual components of the invocation are:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${PROJECT_JS_DIR}/${PROJECT}.js
```

The file or files produced by this custom command. It says: "the custom command produces these files."

```
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${ALL_SOURCES} interface/glue_wrapper.cpp --post-js glue.js -o output.js
```

The `COMMAND` parameter introduces the command-line of the command to be executed. It says: "this is what you must do to produce the files listed in `OUTPUT`."

```
  DEPENDS ${ALL_SOURCES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/interface/glue_wrapper.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/interface/glue.cpp
```

The `DEPENDS` section introduces dependencies (prerequisites) of the command. Each item which follows it is one file which is the command's dependency. It says: "if any of these files is missing, or if *any* of these files is newer than *any* of the output files, this command must be re-run."

Notice in particular the dependency on `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/interface/glue.cpp`, I will come back to it later.

```
  COMMENT "Building ${PROJECT}.js"
```

This is purely documentation—it will be printed when the custom command gets executed (=built).

```
  VERBATIM
)
```

This tells CMake to properly escape any special characters in the `COMMAND` section for the shell which will be executing the command. Basically, always put this into custom commands unless you know for certain you have a reason not to.

**Custom target**

As I've mentioned above, CMake only adds custom commands to the buildsystem if something requests their output. A normal target (i.e. library or executable) can do that by listing the output file among its source files. This is typical in cases when the custom command generates a C++ source file, for example from an IDL definition.

A custom command can also list the output of another custom command in its `DEPENDS` section, which creates the required dependency. However, both will again only be included if the output of the "master" command is requested somewhere.

If the generated file is actually the final product instead of just a source file for a normal target, an explicit dependency on it has to be specified *somewhere* to make sure it's generated. That's where the custom target comes in. It's a target (just like an executable or library), so it will always be present in the buildsystem. When using a makefile-based generator, the custom target is simply an extra rule. Let's analyse the one I put in the answer above:

```
add_custom_target(
  JsLibrary
```

`JsLibrary` is just the symbolic name for the target. It can be anything you want. It's the name you'll type on the command line to build the `.js` file: `> make JsLibrary`.

```
ALL
```

By default, custom targets are *not* part of the `all` target invoked by `make all`; you have to `make` them explicitly. Adding the `ALL` argument makes the custom target part of `make all`, which I assumed you'd want here.

```
DEPENDS ${PROJECT_JS_DIR}/${PROJECT}.js
```

This is the crucial line and the reason why we've created the custom target in the first place. This tells CMake that the custom target depends on the generated file. Now CMake sees the file is required by something which is a part of the buildsystem (i.e. by the custom command `JsLibrary`) and looks to see if it knows how to create such a file. It finds the custom command, and ensures the proper rules will be added to the generated buildsystem.

```
  COMMENT "Building JsLibrary"
)
```

This is pure documentation again—it will be printed each time the target gets made (even if all of its dependencies are up to date and thus no further processing occurs).

**Summing up**

`JsLibrary` will be included in the buildsystem because it's a custom target and custom targets are always included. It will be part of `make all` because we specified `ALL` when creating it.

`JsLibrary` depends on `${PROJECT_JS_DIR}/${PROJECT}.js`, so the rule created by the custom command will be included in the buildsystem and will be checked each time `JsLibrary` is built. If out of date, it will be executed.

`${PROJECT_JS_DIR}/${PROJECT}.js` in turn depends on `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/interface/glue.cpp`, because that was specified in the `DEPENDS` section of the custom command creating the `.js`. So the rule described in the custom command creating `glue.cpp` will also be included in the buildsystem, and everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. But could you explain why glue.cpp is in the for statement `foreach(header IN LISTS my_header_files ITEMS glue.cpp)` is that a mistake?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli No, it's not a mistake. You mentioned you *want* it as the last `#include` in the wrapper, didn't you?

Comment: yes, sorry. I just groked it! (probably as you were replying). 7 hours of staring at the ame lines of code has that brain numbing effect :)!

Comment: This seems to be what I've been struggling to do all day. Let me play around a bit and see if its the solution ...

Comment: Oh, glue_wrapper.cpp has a dependency on glue.cpp, which is built by a python script processing a webIDL file: `python ${PLATFORM_PREFIX}/tools/webidl_binder.py ${myclasses_INTERFACE} glue`

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli But this dependency is only manifested as `#include "glue.cpp"`, right? That is, the *textual contents* of `glue_wrapper.cpp` don't depend on anything build-time. Or, put yet another way, no build-time change can require re-generation of `glue_wrapper.cpp`.

Comment: Sorry for being thick, but I can't seem to see where the file `glue.cpp` is being generated using the python script... Could you please clarify?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I didn't copy that from your question, because that piece of the code will work just fine. At the worst, you'll have to fully qualify paths by judicious application of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`.

Comment: +1 for excellent answer. I copied and pasted your answer and fiddled about a little bit, to get things working - but I don't really understand what you wrote, even though I have read the (very terse) CMake documentation and slept on it. Could you please explain in SIMPLE ENGLISH exactly what the parameters passed into `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target` are actually doing, and why I need a `add_custom_target` even though it doesn't seem like its doing anything (it's not clear what it's actually building - what is JSLibrary ALL, and where is it defined?). Thanks

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Didn't get round to it today, but I will flesh out the answer tomorrow, time permitting.

Comment: I'm waiting for your updated answer, so I can accept your answer (no pressure then ;)

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli It's there.

Comment: Thanks very much for the very detailed explanation. It's all starting to make some sense to me now ;)

Comment: When you have the chance, could you please take a look at my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155364/how-to-print-show-included-directories-in-cmakelist. Thanks