# How to print/show included directories in CMakeList

Tags: build, cmake, makefile

I am trying to build a trivial proof of concept project using CMake, and I am rapidly getting tired of it - to the point that I think it may have been a better idea to handcraft my own damn Makefile.

I have a directory structure that looks something like this:

```
project:
    /extproj
    /src/file.cpp
    /include/file1.h
```

My CMakeLists.txt file contains the following section, which I, having read the CMake documentation, rather naively believed, will be specifying the include directories for the project:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (include/ 
                     extproj/sdk/math/linearalg/ 
                     extproj/sdk/math/nonlinearsolvers/ 
                    )
```

I am trying to build it using the following command

`COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${ALL_SOURCES}`

Where `${ALL_SOURCES}` is a list variable that contains all the C++ files I need to compile. I have verified that this variable contains the correct files.

I can't however, for the life of me, work out what on earth is being passed to the compiler as the include directories.

I searched online, and so a post that recommended using `get_directory_properties`. I tried that and of course CMake immediately failed to generate the Makefile and complained:

`Unknown CMake command "get_directory_properties".`

When I create a Makefile and run make on it, the compiler barfs immediately, with the error message:

> /path/to/project/src/file1.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'file1.h' file not
>   found

Is there ANY WAY, I can find out what on earth is being used as the include paths being passed to my compiler?

Comment: Have you tried `make VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: I take it the `COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ...` is in a custom command. That cannot get affected by `include_directories()` - that command is for CMake invoking the compiler normally (for targets added by `add_executable()` or `add_library()`), not for "custom" invocations you're trying to do.

Comment: @Angew: Running make with `VERBOSE` does indeed confirm that no include files are being passed to the compiler. What I don't understand though (given your second statement), is that the correct compiler - specified in `{CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}` is being used in the custom build (whilst CXX_FLAGS ignored!).  It would seem that some directives are being passed to custom commands, and others are being left behind. I better bite my tongue before I say something extremely rude about CMake.  Unto something more constructive, given the above, how do I access set directives/variables in a custom command?

Comment: Bear in mind that your setup is quite unusual in the first place - driving the compiler manually instead of having CMake do it for you. For compiler invocations CMake knows about, it puts the flags together from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` (or `_DEBUG`), `include_directories()` calls, `target_compile_options()` calls etc. When you run the compiler in a custom command, it's just like any other external command - it will only be run with arguments you explicitly pass in. So just add some `-I`s in there.

Comment: The getter command is `get_directory_property`, BTW. Have you even checked the [CMake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-commands.7.html)?

Comment: I assume this is about the `.js` thing from your last quesiton. Would it be an option for you to "hijack" a normal `add_library` call by manually adding the `--post-js` flag and overriding the output name?

Comment: I will try what you suggested. But it seems CMake has a very half assed approach to custom builds. It either supports it, or it doesn't - which is fine, instead of appearing to build whilst **silently** using only **some** of the previously defined variables. I won't be using it for custom builds again. It would have been quicker to hand roll a Makefile myself. We live and learn.

Comment: Well, if you only want a Makefile, CMake can be overkill. CMake's primary strength is in being buildsystem agnostic - it can produce Visual Studio solutions, XCode projects, Ninja buildfiles etc.

Comment: And it doesn't use "only some variables." It uses precisely the ones you told it to: `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. Nothing suggests this variable should be affected by commands like `include_directories()`, and it is indeed not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way to compile the source files is using 
`add_executable(executableName ${SRCS}`. Then the directories added using `include_directories(...)` get passed to the compiler automatically.

If you are using a custom command to compile you need to change your CMakeLists.txt file.

```
set(MY_INCLUDE_DIRS_FLAGS "-Iinclude/ -Iextproj/sdk/math/linearalg/ -Iextproj/sdk/mat/nonlinearsolvers/")

set(MY_COMPILE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${MY_INCLUDE_DIRS_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${ALL_SOURCES}
```